# Jupyter Notebook and "File/Download as/pdf" not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I can run `jupyter nbconvert SageTest.ipynb --to pdf`without any problem from a terminal window. But doing this directly from the notebook using `File -> Download as -> pdf` will not work: `nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH`. What to do? The same happens if I try to store it as ascii-file: Pandoc not found (but it is installed properly).

My environment: macOS Monterey 12.1, TeXLive2021, Safari 15.3

Comment: Is your notebook running from the same environment and your terminal? It looks like you don't have the right dependencies installed. See https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex

Comment: "from the same environment": Yes, as mentioned: in a terminal session everything is ok. In a browser session it is not working. The path to TeX etc. is ok.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was using the SageMath.app to start the Jupyter notebook - that seems to have a problem to find the right path. If I start jupyter notebook from the terminal, then everything is working. The remark "sane environment" was the right hint.

Comment: I just restarted my Windows computer and everything is working fine using the option directly from Jupyter Notebook. However, you need to be patient.